# No activation function between two convolutional layers in MUNIT?

Tags: convolution, residual-networks, activation-function

I'm reading the code of [NVIDIA's MUNIT](https://github.com/nvlabs/MUNIT), the code of the resnet is as follows:

```py
class ResBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, dim, norm='in', activation='relu', pad_type='zero'):
        super(ResBlock, self).__init__()

        model = []
        model += [Conv2dBlock(dim ,dim, 3, 1, 1, norm=norm, activation=activation, pad_type=pad_type)]
        model += [Conv2dBlock(dim ,dim, 3, 1, 1, norm=norm, activation='none', pad_type=pad_type)]
        self.model = nn.Sequential(*model)

    def forward(self, x):
        residual = x
        out = self.model(x)
        out += residual
        return out

class ResBlocks(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_blocks, dim, norm='in', activation='relu', pad_type='zero'):
        super(ResBlocks, self).__init__()
        self.model = []
        for i in range(num_blocks):
            self.model += [ResBlock(dim, norm=norm, activation=activation, pad_type=pad_type)]
        self.model = nn.Sequential(*self.model)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)
```

I'm confused as to why the activation was set to "none" in the last convolution layer in each ResBlock. I can see that the ResBlock adds a skip connection after the last convolution layer, but after that comes the next ResBlock's convolutional layer. It looks like a sequence of (Conv2D -> Skip connection -> Conv2D) without any non-linearity between them, is this an intentional choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. The same question was asked [in Github issues here](https://github.com/NVlabs/MUNIT/issues/39), the lack of activations is an intentional choice. The paper [Identity Mappings in Deep Residual Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.05027) suggests that *"keeping a “clean” information path (for the skip connections) is helpful for easing optimization"*, which is why there is no activation after the skip connection.